# How to stage and review revised pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

We are adopting Wordpress for a large new project where it needs to function as a content management system (CMS), not just a blogging platform, with pages being constantly revised.

So, one real use case we have is that content owners need to revise multiple pages at one time, and stage those changes in a staging environment, prior to promoting the revised content to production website. We know how this works for new pages, but it appears that Wordpress does not support saving "revisions" to existing pages in a draft or staged form for review.

**Question:** What Wordpress, programming, or devops techniques are available to meet this requirement to review revised content before publishing?

Comment: Check this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-forking/